# opencart cms. Модификации

Tags: opencart

Всем привет!

В opencart есть папка модификации (`system/storage/modification`), у меня установлен шаблон moneymaker2.

Проблема в том, что мне нужно изменить логику работы некоторой части шаблона, редактирование содержимого папки модификации дает лишь временный результат(до первого сброса всех модификаций), где можно найти коренные файлы шаблона, на которые сброс кеша не распространяется?

P.S. В папке catalog этого шаблона нет, модификация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во второй версии OpenCart модификации хранятся в базе данных в таблице {prefix}_modification, чтобы изменения сохранялись после сброса кэшей, исправления надо вносить там. Для более удобной работы с модификациями из административной части магазина есть дополнения, например, Modifications Manager http://www.opencart-templates.co.uk/modification-manager

Answer (score 0):

Для внесения изменений в файлы opencart, при использовании ocMod, необходимо работать с файлами-оригиналами, но не с их копиями из `system/storage/modification`.
Если вы внесёте изменения в файлы модификаций, естественно всё затрётся после первой очистки кеша, т.к. эти файлы будут перезаписаны на основании файлов-оригиналов и тех модификаций, что вы к ним применяете.
В бд, в {prefix}_modification, лежат данные на конкретные расширения, используемые в вашей сборке магазина.